# import.io stuck at Test your connector

Tags: import.io

I have created a connector using import.io windows application.

I am able to successfully test my connector using example queries. I want to extract data returned from this connector into dataset. I am stuck at "Test your connector" option.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Test Connector issue]

Comment: I would like to see what you are experiencing. What is the webpage you are using the Connector with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import.io Connector tool requires multiple queries to ensure it captures the right template. This increases the accuracy of collecting the right dataset.

It has taken me up to 5 queries before seeing "I'm done creating tests."

[image]